# Recommendations for correct healing of a skin wound after removal of stitches?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, eyelids, plastic-surgery

Recently some man had injured my eyes and eyelid skin. My lower eyelid skin was ripped. Lacrimal channel was ripped as well. In the hospital, my wound on the inferior eyelid was stitched. Soon the stitches will be removed. Can I somehow contribute (assist) to the skin and constitution (after stitches removal) to prevent excessive formation of scar tissue and the appearance of a scar?

---

What are recommendations for correct healing of the wound of the skin after removing the stitches and preventing excessive formation of scar (healing) tissue and scars?